# Shell function in makefile may not work

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function):

> The 'shell' function performs the same function that backquotes ('`')
>   perform in most shells: it does "command expansion".  This means that it
>   takes as an argument a shell command and evaluates to the output of the
>   command.  The only processing 'make' does on the result is to convert
>   each newline (or carriage-return / newline pair) to a single space.  If
>   there is a trailing (carriage-return and) newline it will simply be
>   removed.

Version 1 of makefile, is:

```
foo := $(shell echo 'bar'; foo)

all:
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

.PHONY: all
```

Running, we get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: foo: not found
bar
foo is:
```

Version 2 of makefile, is:

```
foo := $(shell echo 'bar'; false)

all:
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

.PHONY: all
```

Running, we get:

```
foo is: bar
```

Now, given the above quote from the documentation:

> The 'shell' function performs the same function that backquotes ('`')
>   perform in most shells: it does "command expansion".

We try and compare the following:

```
# Equivalent to version 1 of makefile above.
$ foo=`echo 'bar'; foo`
sh: 1: foo: not found
$ echo ${foo}
bar

# Equivalent to version 2 of makefile above.
$ foo=`echo 'bar'; false`
$ echo ${foo}
bar
```

So, not only is the shell function not consistent, but it differs from "command expansion" of shells, referenced to, in the docs, cited above!

Is there a rationale behind all this?

Comment: The exit status from `echo 'bar'; foo` is 127; the exit status from `echo 'bar'; false` is 1.  Exit status 127 means that the command failed to execute in some way.  My suspicion is that `make` treats the two exit statuses differently.  Create `makefile.v3` that contains: `foo := $(shell echo 'bar'; exit 127)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Converting a comment into a substantiated answer.*</sup>

The exit status from `echo 'bar'; foo` is 127; the exit status from `echo 'bar'; false` is 1. Exit status 127 means that the command failed to execute in some way.

In the comment, I said that my suspicion is that `make` treats the two exit statuses differently.

When I create `makefile.v3` that contains:

```
foo := $(shell echo 'bar'; exit ${exit})

all:
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

.PHONY: all
```

and run it as shown:

```
$ make -f makefile.v3
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=0
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=1
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=127
bar
foo is: 
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=128
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=129
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=126
foo is: bar
$ make -f makefile.v3 exit=255
foo is: bar
$
```

As hypothesized in the comment, the exit status of `127` is treated differently by `make`.

(For the record: tested with GNU Make 3.81 on Mac OS X 10.10.4.)